# Can I use Theme.DeviceDefault with the androidx.preference library?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, androidx

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to create a really small app for my watch. The app needs to store a username and a password to authenticate the user to another system. So I read that the recommended approach is to use the androidx.preference library to manage the app settings.

The theme of my application is `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"` in the manifest, which should give me the default theme for any device the app runs on. Sounds great to me.

So I have a `MainActivity` with a few buttons, one of them is `Settings` that should take me to a `SettingsActivity` where the user can give his/her credentials.

Here is a minimal example:

MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : Activity() {
// ... standard stuff ...
    fun openSettings(view: View) {
        val settingsIntent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(settingsIntent)
    }

}
```

SettingsActivity.kt:

```kotlin
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

class SettingsActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
    }
}
```

SettingsFragment.kt:

```kotlin
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat


class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        val context = preferenceManager.context
        val screen = preferenceManager.createPreferenceScreen(context)

        val usernamePreference = EditTextPreference(context).apply {
            key = "username"
            title = "Username"
        }

        val passwordPreference = EditTextPreference(context).apply {
            key = "password"
            title = "Password"
            setOnBindEditTextListener { editText ->
                editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
            }
        }

        screen.addPreference(usernamePreference)
        screen.addPreference(passwordPreference)

        preferenceScreen = screen
    }
}
```

activity_settings.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This allows me to click "Settings", takes me to the SettingsActivity and displays two buttons for the settings. But once I click on any of them in the emulator, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:852)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:703)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:421)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:687)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3021)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I read that this exception is caused by using "*Compat" classes but as far as I can see, `PreferenceFragmentCompat` doesn't have a non-Compat counterpart, so I don't know what to do. Is this a limitation of the preference library? Do I have to use some specific AppCompat theme for my app?

Comment: Subclass AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity. You must always use AppCompatActivity if you are using app compat themes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 If I do that, I get the same exception when I try to open the Settings activity. So I think I'm **not** using app compat themes? That's the point of the question, can I use the Theme.DeviceDefault theme, which I assume isn't (or may not be) an app compat theme? I really don't need any specific theme for my app and I'm fine with whatever the device's default one is.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t read carefully. It’s crashing because of the DialogFragment that is started when you click preferences that have dialogs. As far as I know, these can only use AppCompat themes. I think Google highly discourages you from not using AppCompat or some descendent, since device defaults led to some bizarre problems on many apps back in the day. Phone manufacturers would customize the defaults in weird ways that would make text invisible in some apps, for example.

Comment: The DeviceDefault is not an AppCompat theme and should probably be avoided. If you don’t care about your specific theme, just use AppCompat without customizing it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Well, the docs suggested I could use the `DeviceDefault` for a more "native" look and feel on any device, which makes sense for an app with just a few buttons. But your comments and the answers to similar questions here on SO have convinced me that using the DeviceDefault theme is more trouble than it's worth, so I'm moving to an AppCompat theme. Thank you!

Comment: That was the original intent of device default themes. For example, Samsung might have a different default background color for dialog boxes or use a certain font style for Activity title bars. Then if you used that theme in your app your app would look kind of like one of the built-in apps on the phone. But this created many problems like I described above if you did any customization at all of the theme. AppCompat was the solution to that, and it's been around for like 8 years. At this point, I would guess most manufacturers aren't bothering to customize the device default since everyone

Comment: uses AppCompat anyway. Not sure where you read that in the documentation, but possibly they have neglected to update it to what their recommended best practice is now.